# How to export/import multiple styled components from a file?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using a class component and would like to use styled components in it. Here is my code:

styled.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";

export const sInput = styled.input`
margin:1% 0;
padding: 1%;
border: 1px solid black;
background: #323232;
color: ivory;
`;

export const sButton = styled.button`
background: coral;
margin: 0 .5%;
padding: 1%;
border: none;
`;
```

Search.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {sInput, sButton} from "./styled";

class Search extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: ""
        }
    }

    handleChange = e =>{
        this.setState({
            search: e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.search)
    }

    handleSubmit = e =>{
       e.preventDefault();
        console.log("search",this.state.search)
        this.props.search(this.state.search)
        this.setState({
            search:""
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="search">
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="search"></label>
                    <sInput 
                    type="text" 
                    name="search" 
                    value = {this.state.search}
                    placeholder="search your list.." 
                    onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                    <sButton  type="submit" onClick ={this.handleSubmit}>Search</sButton>
                    <sButton  type="submit" onClick = {this.props.clearSearch} >Clear Search</sButton>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

In VS code the import {sInput, sButton} from "./styled"; is greyed out, and says that it isn't being read anywhere in the file. I don't know how else to fix that since my file structure is right. I'm guessing I'm exporting/importing them incorrectly?

edit: Wasn't correctly labeling the styled components, They needed to by capitalized. sInput=>SInput

Comment: Because React components begins with a Capital Letter, `SInput` instead of `sInput`

Comment: Wow, easy fix there. I'm not getting the option to mark this correct, but you got @ShawnYap

Comment: Yep, glad that helped.